# gulp-sass error when installing

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, gulp-sass

I have an error that gets thrown only when I try to install gulp-sass. I have tried installing other modules, (like gulp-livereload) and they work fine. Using npm version 6.0.0. Here is the package.json section that is requiring it:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

The only one here that throws errors is gulp-sass. This is the error:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@6.11.2 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 6.11.2
gyp verb command install [ '6.11.2' ]
gyp verb install input version string "6.11.2"
gyp verb install installing version: 6.11.2
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 6.11.2
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/craigbertrand/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: I have already tried running `npm cache clean`, no difference

Comment: try installing  "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",

Comment: I have, same result. :(

Comment: have you seen the permission denied error for mkdir

Comment: hmm...didn't see that earlier, I tried deleting node_modules and running `sudo npm install`, but got the exact same error with the permission denied line. I also tried this is in a test directory on my desktop and had the same error.

Comment: What's your version of node?

Comment: node version 6.11.2

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this wasn't a permission problem. All I had to do was add the flag `--unsafe-perm=true`. I suppose it is a problem with the gulp-sass postinstaller itself, judging from [this github post](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268). Thanks vishwa for pointing out the permission denied error, I would have never found that post without it. ;)

Comment: Should I open an issue on the gulp-sass repo, or does anyone still think this might be a problem with what I'm doing? Just making sure.

Comment: You could but it's also related to your node version being old. See: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1817